# INSERT … SELECT : missing SELECT keyword

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I am experimenting with a recursive CTE to split a string into multiple values. The data is then inserted into another table.

The following works in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test(data varchar(255));

WITH RECURSIVE
    cte(genres) AS (SELECT 'apple,banana,cherry,date'),
    split(genre,rest,genres) AS (
        SELECT '', genres||',',genres FROM cte
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            substring(rest,0,position(',' IN rest)),
            substring(rest,position(',' IN rest)+1),
            genres
        FROM split WHERE rest<>''
    )
INSERT INTO test(data)
SELECT genre
FROM split;
```

However, the Oracle version:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(data varchar(255));
WITH
    cte(genres) AS (SELECT 'apple,banana,cherry,date' FROM dual),
    split(genre,rest,genres) AS (
        SELECT '', genres||',',genres FROM cte
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            substr(rest,1,instr(rest,',')-1), 
            substr(rest,instr(rest,',')+1),
            genres
        FROM split WHERE rest IS NOT NULL
    )
INSERT INTO test(data)
SELECT genre
FROM split WHERE genre IS NOT NULL;
```

gives me the error message:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword.

Now I’m pretty sure that I’ve got one, there between the `INSERT` and the following `FROM`.

If you comment out the `INSERT`, the rest of it will give the results. Elsewhere, I know that a simple `INSERT … SELECT` does work.

Is it something to do with the recursive CTE? How can I get this to work properly using a standard recursive CTE?

Using Oracle 18c in a Docker image. There is a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d24f3105634933af1b7072bded1dacdf .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INSERT-SELECT means "INSERT" command first, then the SELECT part, and the WITH is part of the SELECT not the insert.

```
SQL> create table t ( x int );

Table created.

SQL> with blah as ( select 1 c from dual)
  2  insert into t
  3  select * from blah;
insert into t
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword


SQL> insert into t
  2  with blah as ( select 1 c from dual)
  3  select * from blah;

1 row created.
```

Comment: That is, the `INSERT` comes before the CTE in Oracle. All the other DBMSs I’ve tried (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL and SQLite) put the CTE first, which I think is more natural, since the purpose of a CTE is to prepare a virtual table and then use it like a normal table. Thanks.